# I did not receive the secret hat for earning a gold badge

Tags: support, bug

According to this answer [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats/288272#288272)

The hat '24' is earned by earning a gold badge. 4 days ago I earned one, but never received the hat. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Presumption is wrong. Mixed up some badges from different years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the 2016 version. This year’s version is here:

[Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats)

This year, the gold badge hat is “foot of the rainbow.”

Your profile on the Leaderboard shows that you do have that one. So, Congrats!